# best solution to use image galllery like TN3 gallery which load images from local drive

Tags: jquery, image

We have an image gallery like TN3 gallery: http://www.tn3gallery.com. The main problem is for security purposes we store images only on local drive. This gallery reads images from html markup or from an XML file which for both of them, the images should be stored on web site folder. Is there a way to read directly from the local drive on server? Does anyone have better image gallery option like this to recommend which support albums?
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

from previous experience I learned that you cannot access a local drive using a scripting language (javascript/php). So you have to store the images on your server instead. The only way I can think of to acheive it, is to reference each image directly in your gallery, which is fine if its a static library and you have no intention of changing it often. If your goal is for it to be dynamic, and reference images automatically, then you will need to store the images on the server.

There are a number of image sliders/galleries available. The ones ive used are [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and [fancyBox](http://fancybox.net/). Creating your own is also fun ;)

Comment: Actually,The images are in a folder on C drive on the server.Each time the page creates we should first copy the images from C drive to web server?? what to do when we have lots of images and albums? Is this a good way to create this ul including lots of list items in the HTML markup? What to do for the performance?

Comment: you could use php to scan the contents of a folder/album and generate an array of the image names. Then using this array you could use javascript to preload the images, and generate your gallery. Some kind of loop(for loop, while loop) would be used to iterate through the images and generate the gallery and thumbnails...